# saved image file is stored with 0kb in sdcard and the folder is not even visible in gallery

Tags: android

in main activity i have a button takeApic that will start the intent to access the camera then on onActivityResult i have passed the bitmap to other activity(ShowActivity)

```
               @Override
              protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        // 2
        Bitmap show_img = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowActivity.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("BitmapImage", show_img);
        startActivity(mIntent);

    }
```

then ShowActivity set the taken image (i have received through intent) in an imageview

```
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    /** retrieve the string extra passed */
    Bitmap our_img = (Bitmap) mIntent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
    mImage.setImageBitmap(our_img);
```

when the button Save is pressed on ShowActivity is should save the image here is my code

```
                 FileOutputStream output;


        File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        // Create a new folder AndroidBegin in SD Card
        File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Hello/");

        dir.mkdirs();

        // Create a name for the saved image
        File file = new File(dir, pic_name+".png");

        // Notify the user on successful save
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image Saved to SD Card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {

            // Image starts saving
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            our_img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);

            output.flush();
            output.close();
        }
        // Catch exceptions
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //  to see saved images in the gallery view.

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

*the program can take picture
*create a folder and image file too
BUT
the file created is of 0KB
and the folder is not visible in gallery

p.s i have given permissions in manifest to write the external storage and access the camera

I will be very very thankful to you if you can please provide me the solution please !!!

Comment: where did you write your output of the bitmap?

Comment: does it create your path? Take away the generic try/catch and look at the logcat afterwards to see what's really happening

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't write the stream to your output file.Try this

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

int remainingData;

while ((remainingData = yourBitmapInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) 

  {

    output.write(buffer, 0, remainingData);

  }
```

for writing streams into your bitmap file.